# spark python unicode error

Tags: python, apache-spark, unicode

I am trying to filter my rdd for one column for one specific value and then taking count . But if I read the column as it is it gives the count as 0
On reading the column as 'str' it gives unicode error

```
bfcrdd = bfcfile.map(lambda l: l.split(",")).filter(lambda l:l[13] == 'Covered')
bfcrdd.count()
```

gives count 0 whereas there are many values in column 13 as the value 'Covered'

on running as

```
bfcrdd = bfcfile.map(lambda l: l.split(",")).filter(lambda l:str(l[13]) ==    'Covered')
bfcrdd.count()
```

gives error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x92' in
>   position 19: ordinal not in range(128)

This is the issue not only with count but collect(), take() also.

Have tried

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

and

```
bfcrdd = bfcrdd.map(lambda p: (p[13].encode("ascii", "ignore"))).collect()
```

but nothing works :(

Comment: Tried this? `p[13].encode('utf-8')`